# sorting (constructor) in Java

Tags: java, sorting, constructor

For example, I have two objects:

```
Icecream ice1 = new Icecream(vanilla, newDate(11, 09, 09));
Icecream ice2 = new Icecream(choko, newDate(10, 08, 08));
// where first argument is a String and second argument is a Date
```

how can I print the out so that they will be ordered by the date starting from earliest? (toStrign method is already configured)

Output sholud be:

```
Vanilla, 10-08-08
Vanilla, 11-09-09
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html - The Oracle tutorial is the third link when googling "java object ordering"

Comment: Search the forum. There are hundreds of example on how to implement the Comparable interface or create a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a natural ordering for your class `IceCream` by implementing the [Comparator](http://A%20comparison%20function,%20which%20imposes%20a%20total%20ordering%20on%20some%20collection%20of%20objects) interface.

```
public class IceCream implements Comparator{
    // ...
    final String name; 
    final Date date;
    public Icecream(String name, Date date){
       this.name = name;
       this.date = date;
    }
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((IceCream)o1).date.compareTo(((IceCream)o2).date);
    }
}
```

Comment: if it not difficult then please show how

Comment: I knew somebody would spoonfeed the answer! So much for learning search skills.

Comment: This answer is wrong: you want to implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, not `Comparator`.  And in either case, you should be using the parameterized type, not the raw type, so it should be `public class IceCream implements Comparable<IceCream>`.

Answer (score 4):

Implement your own comparator and call sort on the collection. Good tutorial is here for example:

[Java Sorting: Comparator vs Comparable Tutorial](http://www.digizol.org/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html)

Comment: +1, for linking to a tutorial and not spoonfeeding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom comparator for your `Icecream` class.

```
class DateComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object ic1, Object ic22){

        /*
         * parameter are of type Object, so we have to downcast it
         * to Icecream objects
         */

        Date ic1Date = ((Icecream)ic1).getDate();        
        Date ic2Date = ((Icecream)ic2).getDate();

        return ic1Date.compareTo(ic2Date);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make two classes, one that implements Comparator and one Sorter that handles the sorting of an array, with a comparator as parameter. Then put the ice creams in a array and call your sort method in Sorter.